# if svn update messes up my local environment how to rollback?

Tags: svn

I am interested in the workflow that is usually followed with svn. If I do an update (this is in an environment without continuous integration or automated regression tests) to get changes of others checkins, sometimes things go horribly wrong. Some piece of functionality 
is broken which may even take a lot of time tracking down who is responsible or to backout of changes... In such cases i just want to have my "before update" environment back...

What is the norm in this case ? I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-base your working copy by:

```
svn update -r <revision_before_trouble>
```

- The SVN client will reverse-merge the changesets between the current working copy version and the older version you are updating to.  To SVN, merging or reverse-merging is the same--it's just applying diffs to files.
- Your local changes are unaffected.  If there is a conflict between a local change and a changeset that is being reverse-merged, the usual SVN merge process applies--i.e. you use `svn resolve` to select the change you want to keep.  You do not simply lose all your local changes.
- This process will put your working copy back to the state before the trouble started.

Comment: would this be less complicated than just making a copy of my directory and if things don't work out renaming it back ?

Comment: Yes!  IMHO, let the tools do the work for you--that's what SVN is designed to do, to make your life easier.  If you're nervous about doing it the first time, go ahead and make a copy of your working copy for safety, but you shouldn't have to do this.  SVN is great!

Comment: I think of it as a change on top of a change, as opposed to undoing a change... I am currently very nervous about trusting tools... long story I hope this does not lead to some trauma disorder (no offense to people with real issues)

Answer (score 1):

If you just roll back to the previous revision number, you will also lose the potential local changes you made before the update (on your working copy), the ones you did not commit to the server before the fateful update, but that were merged during the update.

Usually, everyone that needs to commit a change, would be required to update on its own version first, and check if everything is stable, "tested", or at least compiled (I prefer it is bullet-proof for the next one to come). And then, commit his/her changes. 
Therefore, once you need to update, you have an insurance this update is preserving in one environment, at least.

If the other people you are working with are not cooperative, you can create a branch yourself, and perform merges once needed. You would be able to commit any changes you made before the merge, on your branch. Thus, they will be preserved in case of a havoc.
Another thing you could try is to evaluate "who" perturbs the repository most (in terms of stability from the previous version), and propose them to temporarily develop on another branch.

Comment: I work in an environment where there is no regression testing or even functional testing. we dont have access to creating our own branches. The svn repo is tightly controlled. so i have to think of an alternate solution. I really need help here. Could  I make a backup of my workspace ? What would be the fastest way of doing this ? i could write a little script to encapsulate all that and have some kind of a rollback, The other issue is that the env has other dependencies which in combination with a checkin, can break my env, even though the dev tested things before checkin, rollback only optin

Comment: @treefrog Then, [Colin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116166/william-leara)'s solution is better.

Comment: MarcO, who is Colin and what is his soln ? Oh I get it- William. thx

Comment: Name changed or I messed up copy/pasting. But the link to the user is correct and his answer is [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9998148/493211)

Answer (score 0):

you can always update back to particular revision number.

```
svn up -r <revision_number>
```

Comment: @LazyBadger sorry, i was confused with the option and on my m/c there was no svn install otherwise i could have checked with svn --help

Comment: You have [Net](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re28.html) and [Google](http://www.google.ru/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=svn+help+update&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=qVF7T-j7DI2ZOrSc7MoC)